# Insert statement is executing before delete SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, transactions

I have a statement like below in my stored procedure:

```sql
IF (  
    SELECT COUNT(1)  
    FROM dbo.t_user_suggested
    WHERE ListId = @pListId  
    ) > 0  
  BEGIN  
   DELETE  
   FROM dbo.t_user_suggested
   WHERE ListId = @pListId  
  END

 INSERT INTO dbo.t_user_suggested (  
   Id  
   ,InId  
   ,InName  
   ,UserId  
   ,ListId
   )  
  SELECT DISTINCT Id  
   ,InId  
   ,InName  
   ,@pUserId  
   ,@pListId
  FROM CTE123
```

I am getting error Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_t_user_suggested'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.t_user_suggested'. I have a clear check to delete all records before I insert and this error is coming randomly. I executed stored procedure manually 10-15 times and no error come. How can I ensure the all records are delete before control moves to Insert in my stored procedure.

Comment: SQL is executed sequentially top down, the `INSERT` *will* be executed **after** the `DELETE`. I suspect your `DELETE` is not deleting the rows you think it is *or* you have duplicate values in the rows you are trying to insert. Take the time to create a [mre] and you'll probably find the problem with your existing attempt (it's one of the reasons why you should be trying to create one when asking a question).

Comment: @Larnu: This is exactly my code which is creating the problem.  I have table this table with thousand of rows so could not provide any data. I know its difficult to reproduce it as I am having issues to reproduce it on my end too. I just want to know is there some issue with execution of statements in T-SQL inside a stored procedure as its a very tricky issue.

Comment: @HoneyBadger: Thanks for pointing that out. It was a typo.. No I don't have any trigger on the table t_user_suggested

Comment: So what's the primary key definition on youe table?

Comment: What *is* the PK of this table? I would suggest it is `Id`, and not `ListId`. Since we don't know what `CTE123` is, it is going to be hard to help you

Comment: If executing in parallel, there is a possible race condition between the rows being deleted by the first statements (or not, depending on whether the `IF` races) and being inserted by another session. This cannot happen if this is the only batch operating on the table. Note also that your PK violation is (probably) on `ID` -- you assume but do not prove that deleting all rows with a particular `ListID` would result in something consistent. The one thing you can be certain of is *not* the problem is these statements executing out of order in a single session.

Comment: Intermittent fault - I'd strongly suggest this isn't designed to cope adequately with multiple simultaneous callers, and that's when the errors occur (two users delete, then both try to insert, error)

Comment: PK of this table is (Id,InId ,UserId). Its a composite primary key.

Comment: Try the delete, and see what the select gives you. Compare that to the values in the table. I bet you find you select an `Id,InId ,UserId` already present in the table, with a different `ListId`

Comment: If your PK is (Id,InId ,UserId ) and you delete on ListId level, the process will fail as soon as one user is included in another list - these are not deleted by your statement

Comment: *"This is exactly my code which is creating the problem."* but *we* can't run that SQL, @ChupChapCharli . We don't have access to your instance, nor have DDL and DML for the objects and sample data. Again, take the time to post a [mre] and you will likely find the problem as you do so; but if not post the [mre] and we can explain  why what is happening *is* happening.

Comment: Also, having a physical table called `CTE123` is a little odd of a name, if I am honest. CTE normally means "Common Table Expression"; which is not a physical object (it's an expression, as the name suggests).

Comment: @Larnu:  CTE123 name is just for example purpose.

Comment: @HoneyBadger UserId and ListId have 1 to 1 relationship. I have changed the primary key now on (Id,InId,ListId) now and will see if problem still come.

Comment: @ChupChapCharli That is still not enough, if you want to make sure there are no records for the PK you are inserting, you have to remove all records of that PK, not just a part of it. As Larnu has tried to make clear; We don't know what you are selecting from, we cannot run your code, and we have no data. Without it, we cannot help you further

Comment: @JeroenMostert: How to check and avoid that IF races?

Comment: Add a print or select 'some string' inside the if block and check whether it goes to if Block. Then you can add a print o the deleted rows count to make sure all the data which matches with the filter condition are deleted. Then  select the table with th e filter condition and try to identify the error. I assume that your primary key is ListId. if not you will get this error due to the insert statement with select query can return duplicate values. 

you need to test the program by selecting our insert records. @ChupChapCharli

Comment: This is a suggestion. If you add your table scripts and sample of data which matches to your filter condition, I can have a look. @ChupChapCharli

Answer (score 2):

If two transactions run this code simultaneously, they could both try to insert the same key. Under the default locking/isolation level there is nothing to stop them, moreover you don't appear to be using a transaction anyway.

Your best bet is to use a transaction with the correct hints.

> By the way, there is no need for the `IF (SELECT COUNT(1)...` because the `DELETE` will only delete rows that exist. Also, if you really needed this then you should use `IF(EXISTS` instead

```sql
SET XACT_ABORT, NOCOUNT ON;

BEGIN TRAN;

DELETE
FROM dbo.t_user_suggested WITH (HOLDLOCK)
WHERE ListId = @pListId;
 
INSERT INTO dbo.t_user_suggested (  
   Id  
   ,InId  
   ,InName  
   ,UserId  
   ,ListId
   )  
  SELECT DISTINCT Id  
   ,InId  
   ,InName  
   ,@pUserId  
   ,@pListId
  FROM CTE123;

COMMIT TRAN;
```

Alternatively, if `@pListId` is actually the primary key, then it's much better just to issue an `UPDATE`

```sql
UPDATE 
SET Id = CTE123.InId
   ,InId  = CTE123.InId  
   ,InName = CTE123.InName 
   ,UserId = CTE123.UserId 
FROM dbo.t_user_suggested t
JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT Id  
   ,InId  
   ,InName  
   ,@pUserId AS pUserId
   ,@pListId AS pListId
  FROM CTE123
) CTE123 ON CTE123.pListId = t.pListId
WHERE t.ListId = @pListId;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, (Id,InId,ListId) combination is primary key.

Comment: Then the second version probably won't work for you

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that below query is returning more than one rows. So you are getting same ListID for every row.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Id  
   ,InId  
   ,InName  
   ,@pUserId  
   ,@pListId
  FROM CTE123
```

Please try to execute below query:

```
IF (  
    SELECT COUNT(1)  
    FROM dbo.t_user_suggested
    WHERE ListId = @pListId  
    ) > 0  
  BEGIN  
   DELETE  
   FROM dbo.t_user_suggested
   WHERE ListId = @pListId  
  END

 INSERT INTO dbo.t_user_suggested (  
   Id  
   ,InId  
   ,InName  
   ,UserId  
   ,ListId
   )  
  SELECT top 1 DISTINCT Id  
   ,InId  
   ,InName  
   ,@pUserId  
   ,@pListId
  FROM CTE123
```

I have tried to create your situation and your query is working just fine. You can check below example. Either `ListId` is not your primary key column or your select query is returning multiple rows.

DB-Fiddle:

Table definition and insert statements:

```
 create table t_user_suggested (Id  int ,InId  int,InName  varchar(50),UserId  INT,ListId INT);
 INSERT INTO t_user_suggested values(1,1,'A',2,3);
```

Select query:

```
 select* from t_user_suggested
```

Current output from the table:

| Id | InId | InName | UserId | ListId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | A | 2 | 3 |

Your query:

Deletion part

```
 IF (  
     SELECT COUNT(1)  
     FROM dbo.t_user_suggested
     WHERE ListId = 3
     )  0  
   BEGIN  
    DELETE  
    FROM dbo.t_user_suggested
    WHERE ListId = 3  
   END
```

Select query after deletion:

```
 select * from t_user_suggested;
```

Output:

| Id | InId | InName | UserId | ListId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

Rows have been successfully deleted.

Insert statement:

```
  INSERT INTO dbo.t_user_suggested (  
    Id  
    ,InId  
    ,InName  
    ,UserId  
    ,ListId
    )  
   values(1,1,'A',2,3);
```

Select query after insertion:

```
 select * from t_user_suggested;
```

Ouput:

| Id | InId | InName | UserId | ListId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | A | 2 | 3 |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7aab5205cd117dda6d43e7635bab596d)*

Comment: Hum, good point, always check the obvious first

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is exactly the issue but seems like a race condition or issue with transaction locking/isolation level. I have used a MERGE statement instead of Insert and delete to fix the issue for time being. so below is my query.

```sql
MERGE t_user_suggested AS tar
USING CTE123  AS cte
    ON tar.Id = cte.Id 
        AND tar.InId  = cte.InId  
        AND tar.ListId = @pListId
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY Target
    THEN
        INSERT (
            Id 
            ,InId  
            ,InName
            ,UserId
            ,ListId
            )
        VALUES (
            cte.Id
            ,cte.IngrId
            ,cte.InName
            ,@pUserId
            ,@pListId
            )
     -- For Updates
    WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
        tar.IName       = cte.InName,
        tar.datetimelastseen = null,
        tar.seenlast24hours=null
        -- For Deletes
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
        DELETE;
```

Comment: [`MERGE` won't help you for locking problems by itself, you still need `HOLDLOCK`](https://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/2009/01/31/upsert-race-condition-with-merge/)